# Android XML: How to place widget below included layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to place a chart widget (com.android.AnyChartView, **@+id/piechart**) from the AnyChart library (https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android) below an included layout (**@layout/content_main**) that contains a `TabHost`. I tried giving the `include` an id and setting the `layout_below` property of the chart widget, but that has not worked. The app graph fills the entire screen, covering the Tab view.

Below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
         />

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/piechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tab_host"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is a screenshot of the app:
[image]

Comment: try adding weight to both layout or put them in scrollview

Comment: Put your Chart Widget below the TabHost in Constraint layou !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your pie chart from `main_activity` and put it under `content_main` like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <TabHost
            android:id="@+id/tab_host"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>


        <com.anychart.AnyChartView
            android:id="@+id/piechart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_host" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have added the `scrollview` but you can remove it if it's not in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible solutions

**Solution 1**

On the `include` tag indicate `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android_height="wrap_content"`

```java
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

**Solution 2**

Using `LinearLayout` as the parent `ViewGroup` provide `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` on the `include` tag, this will allow the `content_main.xml` to occupy the remaining space and yet fit on the screen.

```java
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android_height="0dp"
     android_layout_weight="1"
  />
```